# Scrolling UIScrollView - block main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have weird problem while UITableView is scrolling I'm not able to invoke any events (touch down button, change layout colour). Funny thing is that when I touches on UISeachBar, the keyboard appears immediately.
I realize that main thread has been blocked, however I wonder is there any solution to fix this problem.

Comment: Show your code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, when scrolling that method is constantly invoked to refresh the cell's

Answer (score 1):

With the short description of your problem, I suppose that it is because when you scroll your tableView run loop change from `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` to `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` (see [Run loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW20))

To change your UI while scrolling, the solution seems to perform your UI updates on the `NSRunLoopCommonModes` which includes the two loop mode you target.

Be prevent that it could make your tableview scrolling clunky.

Comment: But how to perform UI updates on NSRunLoopCommonModes, how to change  handling events like user interaction (touch down on button).
That's weird because I had other clean project where this problem doesn't occurs.

Comment: I think it's very difficult to find what can be the problem without more informations. Do you try to isolate this behavior with less code? Once isolated you can share it on stackoverflow and we'll be able to help you more